# Use webpack to bundling node_modules and running code in multiple entry points?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm running a system which runs node on a server but it does not allow me to deploy `node_modules`

In order to work with dependencies, I see the only solution to bundle them inside a `vendors.js` file.

Furthermore, the system only allows for es5 javascript so the javascript needs to be transpiled and polyfilled.

The current setup I have today looks something like this:

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require("path");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const glob = promisify(require("glob"));

const babelconfig = require("./.babelrc");

const generateEntries = async () => {
  return (
    await glob("./src/**/*(*.ts|*.mjs)", {
      ignore: "./src/**/*.d.ts"
    })
  ).reduce((acc, item) => {
    const chunkName = path.basename(item, path.extname(item));
    acc[chunkName] = item;
    return acc;
  }, {});
};

module.exports = async () => {
  return {
    target: "node",
    entry: await generateEntries(),
    mode: "production",
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".mjs"]
    },
    externals: /(\*|server)/i,
    optimization: {
      minimize: false,
      runtimeChunk: {
        name: "vendor"
      },
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          commons: {
            chunks: "initial",
            minChunks: 2,
            maxInitialRequests: 5,
            minSize: 0
          },
          vendor: {
            test: /node_modules/,
            chunks: "all",
            name: "vendor",
            priority: 10,
            enforce: true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "/lib"),
      filename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /(m?\.js|\.ts)/,
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: babelconfig
        }
      ]
    }
  };
};
```

**.babelrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            "@babel/typescript",
            {
                debug: true,
            },
        ],
        [
            "@babel/env",
            {
                useBuiltIns: "entry",
                targets: {
                    ie: "9",
                },
                corejs: "3",
                debug: true,
            },
        ],
    ],
    plugins: [
        "add-module-exports",
        "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread",
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
            {
                regenerator: true,
            },
        ],
    ],
}
```

The transpilation/compilation works fine, however when i try to run the actual code, the compiled methods do not seem to execute:

When taking a very simple typescript file with the following source:

**test.ts**

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

The tranpiled version looks like this:

```
exports.ids = [2];
exports.modules = {

/***/ 8:
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

console.log("Hello World");

/***/ })

};;
```

Which of-course doesn't output anything since its wrapped in `exports.modules`
What am I doing wrong here?

Running the file (test.ts) directly with babel-cli produces the following file:

```
"use strict";

console.log("Hello World");
```

Which works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using rollup rather than webpack with the following config:

```
const extensions = [".mjs", ".ts", ".js"]
const bundle = await rollup.rollup({
    input: (
        await glob(`${options.outDir}/${cartage}/${TARGET_FILES}`, {
            ignore: `${options.outDir}/${cartage}/**/*.d.ts`,
        })
    ).reduce((acc, file) => {
        const pathName = file.substring(options.outDir.length + 1)
        const entryName = path.basename(pathName, path.extname(pathName))

        acc[
            `${(pathName.indexOf("/") !== -1 &&
                `${path.dirname(pathName)}/`) ||
                ""}${entryName}`
        ] = file
        return acc
    }, {}),
    external: id => id == "server" || /^\*/.test(id),
    plugins: [
        resolve({ extensions }),
        babel({
            extensions,
            runtimeHelpers: true,
        }),
        commonjs({ extensions }),
        strip({
            labels: ["outer"],
        }),
    ],
})

const outputOptions = {
    dir: CARTAGE_TRANSPILE_DIR,
    format: "cjs",
    sourcemap: true,
    chunkFileNames: `${cartage}/[name]-[hash].js`,
}

await bundle.write(outputOptions)
```